# Interpreting powers in perl using regex

Tags: regex, perl, math, eval

I'm trying to read in two numbers separated by a `:` and perform a comparison.

Below is some code that illustrates my problems:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @nums = qw(1.23:2.13 0.1:2.11 1.17772e+06:1.32 2:10.2);

for my $number (@nums){
    print "actual numbers $number\n";
    my ($c, $e) = ($1, $2) if $number =~ /(\d+\.\d+|\d+):(\d+\.\d+|\d+)/;
    print  "regex matches: $c:$e\n";
}
```

Which outputs:

```
actual numbers 1.23:2.13
regex matches: 1.23:2.13
actual numbers 0.1:2.11
regex matches: 0.1:2.11
actual numbers 1.17772e+06:1.32
regex matches: 06:1.32 # not capturing 1.17772e+06
actual numbers 2:10.2
regex matches: 2:10.2
```

My question is: How can I a) capture `1.17772e+06` and b) evaluate it as a number?

Comment: You should not use a conditional together with declaration assignment `my $var = $foo if ...`, as I recall, that behaviour is undefined. (If it fails, does `$var` exist?)

Comment: @toolic - thanks. I usually would, but I'm capturing the numbers from a line containing other info. I've changed my code to now capture the part of the line containing the numbers, and then later split on `:` - which works perfectly. I'll post up the code as a solution - unless you want to change your comment to an answer?

Comment: @FlyingFrog It's not a tip, its fact. You might note that it is ok to write `my ($var) = $number =~ /..../`, because the regex will return an empty list if it fails to match. So `$var` will still exist, but it will contain `undef`.

Answer (score 5):

From [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html):

```
/^(?:[+-]?)(?=\d|\.\d)\d*(?:\.\d*)?(?:[Ee](?:[+-]?\d+))?$/
```

Or,

```
use Regexp::Common;
/$RE{num}{real}/
```

(These assume you want Perl's definition of a number.)

Answer (score 3):

I would just use the split function (`split /:/`) here.